# How to avoid to show custom app lock screen display while using camera or photoLibrary in iOS?

Tags: ios

In my iOS App i need to display custom app lock screen while App moving from foreground to background.

i have done that in **applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)**

but my problem is while camera or photo library, the App lock screen displaying. because at that time **applicationWillResignActive** is calling.

how to avoid to display custom app lock screen for camera/photo library.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom app lock screen"? It sounds like something no user desires. If all you are looking to do is display a screen when your app goes into the background (and hopefully do something when becoming active again) then why do you care what you "app" does when it calls `UIImagePickerController`? (I'm assuming this because you've shown **no** code whatsoever. Please, give us code - something we can reproduce your issue from. It helps us help you.)

Comment: AppLock screen means viewcontroller which needs to enter security code.

i am presenting that view controller in AppResignActive. once security code entered i am dismissing that view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now, could you provide some code - what have you tried?